# Anonymous block in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand below code - What is the use of below anonymous block

```
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World2");
}
```

Above code is available inside a method - I am new to c# and trying to understand it .

Comment: If some code is wrapped in anonymous blocks, its scope is limited by the brackets of the block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use in this example: none.

Use of an anonymous block: acts just like any block, with its own scope.

eg, this code will not compile as `a` is not in scope outside the block:

```
{
    var a = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

You can read more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500006/what-is-the-purpose-of-anonymous-blocks-in-c-style-languages), although that is geared slightly to c/c++ but mostly holds true in c#. A more existential discussion is also available [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361517/does-it-make-sense-to-create-blocks-just-to-reduce-a-variables-scope).

Comment: Note that in C# 8 there is a new point to anonymous blocks: When the scope ends, any disposables introduced within the scope via a [`using declaration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations) will be disposed at the end of the scope.

Comment: Really good point @MatthewWatson but I wonder if you're going to use them like that why you wouldnt just use the older `using(var x = new DisposibleThing()){ ... }` method of introducing a block.

Comment: @Jamiec Lack of knowledge. Most of the times I see (especially on SO) newbies use odd constructions, it's because they don't know any better. I may be guilty of this, too. Or have been. That's not necessarily the person's fault. Just last week I saw a teacher make the students use out-of-the-world code without any justification.

Comment: Yes, I would always use an explict "using" block in those cases, but I thought it worth pointing out.