# How to set a while loop?

Tags: c#, math, random, while-loop

I'm trying to set my code for counting math games, all math operations are fine except for division. I don't know how to set the while loop correctly. There is a problem with division, such that I would like the division to be residual, so I came up with one method which is given below. It is all in WPF Application. I would like to count only single-digit numbers.

```
Random number = new Random();
int maxValue = 10;
int total = 0;
int firstNumber = number.Next(1, maxValue);
int secondNumber = number.Next(1, firstNumber);
while (firstNumber % secondNumber != 0);
  {
  secondNumber++;
  }
total = firstNumber / secondNumber;
```

Why does it still show me the values ​​that have a residual division?

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of your `while` statement (this terminates the loop immediately)

Comment: You should learn how to single-step code in the debugger, and then you'd see the issue pretty quickly! Also, Visual Studio should be showing a [CS0642](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0642?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0642)) warning for the extraneous semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semi colon at the end of line:

```
while (firstNumber % secondNumber != 0);
```

...ends the while loop. The code in the remaining block is executed without any condition (as it in fact is a [anonymous block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500006/what-is-the-purpose-of-anonymous-blocks-in-c-style-languages)):

```
{
    secondNumber++;
}
```